# Publishing error from ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I was trying to upload a CSV file on ArcGIS with Python.
I wrote the code :

```py
import pandas as pd
from arcgis import GIS
import os
import datetime
import shutil

URL = "https://www.arcgis.com/"
gis = GIS(url=URL, username="nimish", password="############")
csv1 = '/home/nimish/PycharmProjects/freelancer/project6/csv_files/capitals_1.csv'
cities_df_1 = pd.read_csv(csv1)
print(cities_df_1.head())
print(cities_df_1.shape)

data_pth = "/home/nimish/PycharmProjects/freelancer/project6/csv_files/backup/"
now_ts = str(int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()))  # current timestamp

# copy the file, appending the unique string and assign it to a variable
my_csv = shutil.copyfile(os.path.abspath(csv1),
                         os.path.join(data_pth, 'capitals_1_' + now_ts + '.csv'))

item_prop = {'title': 'Sample spreadsheet ' + now_ts}
csv_item = gis.content.add(item_properties=item_prop, data=my_csv)
print(csv_item)

cities_item = csv_item.publish()
print(cities_item)

item_prop = {'title': 'USA Capitals'}
cities_item.update(item_properties=item_prop, thumbnail='data/updating_gis_content/capital_cities.png')

# Uploaded first CSV uptil here
```

But it displays an error
RuntimeError: Unable to publish item.
User 'nimishbansal' does not have publishing privileges.
(Error Code: 400)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I switched to a developer account and was able to publish it. It might be because developer account gives the permission for performing publishing of item and other stuff as well